# How to pass a value from a child to a parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, a parent component and a child component (the code is incorrect, just to understand what I want to do):

```js
export default class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            count: 0;
        }
    }
    clickFunction() {
        this.state.count += 1
    }
    render() {
        return <div>
            <div onClick={this.clickFunction} class={myClass}>PressMe</div>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    }
}

export default class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            count: 0,
        }
    }
    render() {
        return <Child ref={this.state.count}>
            <p>Count: {this.state.count}!</p>
        </Child>
    }
}
```

In fact, I need the `child.state.count` to be incremented by 1 when `dev:myClass` is clicked and this value is somehow passed to the parent component.

How do I fix these components to make it work the way I want it to?

P.S. I know very little about React, so I'd be happy if you could tell/drop documentation about `state` (what it's for and where and how to set it correctly in these components).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the state in parent, create a function in parent to change the state, pass that function to child component, call the function from child like below.
`this.props.clickFunction()` do that work from child component.

Child -

```
export default class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        count: 0,
    }
  }

render() {
    return <div>
        <div onClick={() => this.props.clickFunction()} class={myClass}>PressMe</div>
        {this.props.children}
    </div>
 }
}
```

Parent -

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        count: 0,
    }
  }
clickFunction() {
    this.setState({
        count: this.state.count  + 1
    })
}
render() {
    return <Child clickFunction={this.clickFunction} ref={this.state.count}>
        <p>Count: {this.state.count}!</p>
    </Child>
 }


}
```

Comment: I think there must be some better way (like `$emit` in Vue), but this worked.